# Why is the file size growing each time the word document is saved using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, save-as

I have a VBA Macro I wrote that takes data from a spreadsheet to generate word documents.

For the most part all the information that is generated is exactly the same except for a few fields that denote contact info and amounts. All the files start out saved at 17kb but as the macro run through the spreadsheet those file sizes grow. After about 2500 saves the files were up to 48kb.

I am not sure why this is happening. I was thinking maybe some kind of meta data is being held onto after each time the doc is deleted and written to again.

I have tried a few things to remove metadata but I am not sure I am doing this correctly as there is not a whole lot out there I could find on this kind of issue.

In an attempt to make this run a little quicker I have build the macro to open a blank word document and then as it loops through all the rows on the spreadsheet is copies the final information to the word doc, SaveAs a unique value in a folder then deletes the content of the word doc and then does the whole thing over again until its iterated through all the rows on the worksheet.

Is there something about how I am generating my files that is causing the growth of the word docx files?

After going into each file that is generated (hundreds) it appears to be growing by 20b on average each new document generated. So the file size slowly but constantly grows each save.

Here is a sample of what the growth looks like over each new document saved.

[image]

Here is an example of how the KB are growing over time.

[image]

Here is the overall macro stripped down.

```
Sub GenerateLetterForSelectedMonth()
    Dim temp_wb, data_wb As Workbook
    Dim temp_ws, data_ws As Worksheet
    Dim ltr_str1, ltr_str2, wb_dir, file_path As String
    Dim account_num, cust_name, non_etf_amt, etf_amt, plcmt_amt, mex_act, adr1, adr2, city, state, zip, country, cont_name As String
    Dim last_row1 As Long
    Dim objWord As Object
    ' Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set temp_wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set temp_ws = temp_wb.Worksheets(1)
    wb_dir = temp_wb.Path

    ' Select file to process '
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    ' open file to process '
    Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(file_path)
    Set data_ws = data_wb.Worksheets(1)

    ' get last row of file being processed '
    last_row1 = data_ws.Range("A" & data_ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' check for todays folder if not exist then create '
    Dim path_ As String
    path_ = wb_dir & "\DOCS " & Format(Now, "MMMM-dd-yyyy")

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(path_) Then .CreateFolder path_
    End With


    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.Visible = False

    For i = 2 To last_row1

        mex_act = UCase(data_ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)
        account_num = data_ws.Cells(i, 1)
        cust_name = data_ws.Cells(i, 2)
        non_etf_amt = data_ws.Cells(i, 3)
        etf_amt = data_ws.Cells(i, 5)
        plcmt_amt = data_ws.Cells(i, 6)
        adr1 = data_ws.Cells(i, 8)
        adr2 = data_ws.Cells(i, 9)
        city = data_ws.Cells(i, 10)
        state = data_ws.Cells(i, 11)
        zip = data_ws.Cells(i, 12)
        country = data_ws.Cells(i, 13)
        cont_name = WorksheetFunction.Proper(data_ws.Cells(i, 14))

        temp_ws.Cells(3, 1).Value = _
            Format(Now, "MMMM-dd-yyyy") & vbNewLine & cust_name & vbCr & adr1 & " " & adr2 & vbCr & city & ", " & state & " " & zip & vbNewLine & _
            "redacted for post " & "****" & Mid(account_num, 5, 10) & vbNewLine & "Dear " & cont_name & ":" & vbNewLine & "redacted for post" & plcmt_amt & _
            "redacted for post" & vbNewLine & "redacted for post" & non_etf_amt & vbCr & "redacted for post" & etf_amt & vbNewLine & "redacted for post" _

        'Copy the range Which you want to paste in a New Word Document
        temp_ws.Range("A2:A6").Copy

        With objWord
            .Selection.WholeStory
            .Selection.Paste
            .DefaultTableSeparator = " "
        End With

        objWord.ActiveDocument.RemoveDocumentInformation (wdRDIAll)
        objDoc.SaveAs Filename:=path_ & "\" & data_ws.Cells(i, 1)

        With objWord
            objDoc.Range(0, 0).Select
            .Selection.WholeStory
            .Selection.Delete
        End With
        Debug.Print (i)
    Next i

    objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```

Comment: If I've understood well: **case 1** your code generates 10 identical word documents in one shot (only difference is the information, but the quantity is the same). The first file will size 17k, the 10th file will size 17k + 20k*9 even though it contains the same amount of info than the first. **case 2** you run the macro to generate 1 single word document sized 17k. You repeat this exercise other 9 times, and each document is sized 17k (because each document is the first of each run). Am I getting it right?

Comment: Are you tracking changes? (See: Review tab)

Comment: Yes. I am thinking I already found the solution. I changed a section of the colde that after saving the objDoc it does a `.Close` then `Set objDoc = Nothing` and this appears to have fixed the file growth. So something in the `objDoc` was keeping some info after each save. I just dont know what at this point.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ the files sizes were only going up by 5 to 20 bytes per save. This added up to a total of 48kb over the 2500 documents being generated. I have at least figured out that the portion that was gaining data per save was the actual doc object within the word object.

Comment: Reinitializing `objDoc` is what I was going to suggest if your answer was positive. Glad you found a solution. I wouldn't know why it behaves like this, but if you want to find it out for sake of science, you can generate 10 sample files, change their extension to `.zip` and open each one of them with a folder viewer: you should spot the cumulative information that will most probably be cache data from your previous save.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ if it is cache data is there a way (other than reinitializing the `objDoc`) to tell word via VBA to dump the cache?

Comment: I don't think MS Word code exposes such an API to dump the cache. I think the object just behaves like a standard Word document (and Word for final users doesn't offer any of these functionalities). What's wrong with re-initializing it each run? Is it slowing down your macro?

Comment: It was when I was reinitializing the `objWord` but it does not appear to be slowing down or at least not by much when I reinitialize the 'objDoc' object in the word object so that will work for now. Before I posted here I had tried with the 'objWord' and it slowed down a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some guess work I did figure out at least what object was holding onto date each time the file was saved.

I ended up having to completly close and set to `Nothing` the `objDoc` and then re add the `objDoc` each run of the loop. This got rid of the growth of the file size I was looking at.

I still do not know why it was growing so if someone know that bit I would love to know for sure why it happened and not just what it was happening to.

The new code if anyone is interested is below:

```
Sub GenerateLetterForSelectedMonth()
    Dim temp_wb, data_wb As Workbook
    Dim temp_ws, data_ws As Worksheet
    Dim ltr_str1, ltr_str2, wb_dir, file_path As String
    Dim account_num, cust_name, non_etf_amt, etf_amt, plcmt_amt, mex_act, adr1, adr2, city, state, zip, country, cont_name As String
    Dim last_row1 As Long
    Dim objWord As Object
    ' Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set temp_wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set temp_ws = temp_wb.Worksheets(1)
    wb_dir = temp_wb.Path

    ' Select file to process '
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    ' open file to process '
    Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(file_path)
    Set data_ws = data_wb.Worksheets(1)

    ' get last row of file being processed '
    last_row1 = data_ws.Range("A" & data_ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' check for todays folder if not exist then create '
    Dim path_ As String
    path_ = wb_dir & "\DOCS " & Format(Now, "MMMM-dd-yyyy")

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(path_) Then .CreateFolder path_
    End With


    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    For i = 2 To last_row1
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add ' ADDED THIS LINE
        mex_act = UCase(data_ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)
        account_num = data_ws.Cells(i, 1)
        cust_name = data_ws.Cells(i, 2)
        non_etf_amt = data_ws.Cells(i, 3)
        etf_amt = data_ws.Cells(i, 5)
        plcmt_amt = data_ws.Cells(i, 6)
        adr1 = data_ws.Cells(i, 8)
        adr2 = data_ws.Cells(i, 9)
        city = data_ws.Cells(i, 10)
        state = data_ws.Cells(i, 11)
        zip = data_ws.Cells(i, 12)
        country = data_ws.Cells(i, 13)
        cont_name = WorksheetFunction.Proper(data_ws.Cells(i, 14))

        temp_ws.Cells(3, 1).Value = _
            Format(Now, "MMMM-dd-yyyy") & vbNewLine & cust_name & vbCr & adr1 & " " & adr2 & vbCr & city & ", " & state & " " & zip & vbNewLine & _
            "redacted for post " & "****" & Mid(account_num, 5, 10) & vbNewLine & "Dear " & cont_name & ":" & vbNewLine & "redacted for post" & plcmt_amt & _
            "redacted for post" & vbNewLine & "redacted for post" & non_etf_amt & vbCr & "redacted for post" & etf_amt & vbNewLine & "redacted for post" _

        'Copy the range Which you want to paste in a New Word Document
        temp_ws.Range("A2:A6").Copy

        With objWord
            .Selection.WholeStory
            .Selection.Paste
            .DefaultTableSeparator = " "
        End With

        objWord.ActiveDocument.RemoveDocumentInformation (wdRDIAll)
        objDoc.SaveAs Filename:=path_ & "\" & data_ws.Cells(i, 1)
        objDoc.Close  ' ADDED THIS LINE
        Set objDoc = Nothing  ' ADDED THIS LINE

    Next i

    objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```

Comment: I've been thinking about this, trying to dredge up everything I've heard and read the last 20 years... Best might be to ask in an end-user venus as someone there may have more experience with the behavior when re-saving a document again, and again. **Important**: specify the version of Word and do NOT mention code. You might also open two such documents in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and use the compare feature to see how the underlying Word Open XML differs - that should give you important clues...

Comment: ... You might also try to re-open one of these, then save and close again (which might remove "left-overs" retained from the previous editing). Mostly, Word saves "undo" information outside the document, but it may well be doing some internal tracking inside it...

Comment: @CindyMeister the reopen options greatly slows down the macro. So does saving closing and then creating new word object. I needed to fix the issue without the massive increase in time spent running the macro. I will probably head over to end-user and post when I get back to work though. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You asked *why* it was happening. My remarks were directed at that and not meant as possible approaches for achieving the goal. For achieving your goal you should start with a *template* (dotx) and use `Documents.Add` for each new document, rather than trying to re-use the same document. That's standard Word usage, whether for end-users or developers...